# Bad mathchar with semantic package

Tags: package-options

I get the following error message when using the `semantic` package:

```
   ! Bad mathchar (32768).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.13 \begin{document}
```

The problem goes away if I load the `semantic` package with just the `inference` option. However, I do need math ligatures (the `\mathlig` command).

Also, the problem disappears if I do not load the `mathtools` package. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{semantic}

% \usepackage{mathtools}     % Uncommenting this causes the problem.

\mathlig{->}{\rightarrow}
\mathlig{|->}{\mapsto}

\begin{document}

Here is a formula: $a -> b |-> c$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Just switch the loading order: first `mathtools`, then `semantic`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes the MWE work, but breaks other random things, like for example ``$a^*$``. The solution is of course to write ``$a^{*}$`` instead.

Just felt like leaving this here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `semantic` package documentation doesn’t explicitly tell that `amsmath` should be loaded before it.

Since `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, the same applies.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools} % must go before semantic
\usepackage{semantic}

\mathlig{->}{\rightarrow}
\mathlig{|->}{\mapsto}

\begin{document}

Here is a formula: $a -> b |-> c$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not really sure of the advantage of `->` over `\rightarrow` and `|->` over `\mapsto`.

Comment: I write programming language semantics, and being able to read inference rules in-source is of great value. Consider for example``\mathlig{-->*}{\longrigharrow^{*}}``, standing for the transitive reflexive closure of some pre-defined --> relation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix:

Add the code :

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[mathpazo]{flexisym}
```

PS: Found the fix [here](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29218)

Comment: Thanks for your response; however, it did not fix my problem. I am now getting

`! Undefined control sequence.
\binrel@@ #1->\@symErr 
                       ?{\OrdSymbol {#1}}
l.43   \paralonen`

Please see my edited question for a minimal working example.